# How to find the url of the saved web page?

Tags: web, url

I am facing this issue since long. I open a web page and save on my hard drive.
Later I open the saved file. But suppose I want to know the url of the same page, how to know that. As I have no idea of how to get the url, I again have to search for the page in google. Does url also gets saved somewhere while saving the web page?

Comment: Use bookmarks as well?

Answer (score 2):

> Does url also gets saved somewhere while saving the web page?

Unless your browser inserted it into the title or something, no. It probably won't be in the page itself -- and if it appears to be, there's no guarantee that's accurate, either, since there's likely no need or purpose to it in the mark-up.

Comment: While saving browser isn't inserting the url but there must be a way or a setting so that I can force bowser to do so whenever any page is saved! Any idea please!

Comment: Maybe, but that would be browser specific.  I think recent FF versions give you an option about how to save the page and if you select one that includes the images, etc, you get a directory with the URL in the name?  Anyway, you'd be better off asking that question on http://superuser.com/ since it's not about unix/linux.